# A manga about two boys originally from an orphanage

Tags: aegis

First, I want to inform that I'm French, so I'm sorry for my bad English...

I'm desperately looking for a manga that I can not manage to find despite all my efforts. On the dozen forums where I was searching, I found nothing. I remember only few scenes of the story:

- It talks about two boys in an orphanage who plan to flee when one of them is going to be adopted. But in the end, they are taken together.
- Some years later, they are in a kind of army. For a reason that I don't remember anymore, one of the boys escaped from the organization and hid himself among the society, where he attended high school.
- But one day, his old friend is ordered to get him.
- I read it around 3 years ago. One of the boys has black hair and seemed to be cold with others. And I think the second boy was blond.

Here's all I know, I hope that I've been understood.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Your English is fine, and you've used formatting properly - which is a very refreshing sight! If you can remember any other details, make sure to edit them into your post -  the more you tell us, the more likely we are to be able to help you out.

Comment: When did you read the manga? What do the characters look like? Details like that will help immensely.

Comment: I edited the post to answer your question.

Comment: Do you remember what kind of weapons they fought with, guns/blades or something different? In what kind of setting is it set, Post apocalyptic or anything else?

Comment: I said two days ago that I have found the manga. Aegis is the title and actually I totally forgot it was a manhwa. I also mixed some parts of what I remembered with another manga, sorry! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I finally found it! It's Aegis. Someone just told me the title on a forum. I also mixed some parts of the story with another, sorry. Thank you again for your answers.